# Typescript interface method overload doesn't work

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```
class A { }

class B { }

class C { }

interface Builder {
    build(paramOne: A): string;
    build(paramOne: B, paramTwo: C): number;
}

class Test implements Builder {
    build(a: A) {
      return 'string';
    }
}
```

Why I'm getting an error from typescript on the `build()` method? I'm expecting that typescript will know that when I pass only one param with type `A`, it should return a string.

Comment: What error do you get and on which build? You have 3 of them

Comment: Because interface is not fully implemented.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-77rou1

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-1u1g47

Comment: @AlekseyL. Thanks. So I need to repeat this on every class that implements Builder?

Comment: You need to provide full implementation for the interface. It could be also a base class - depends on real use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface implementation will need to have the public overloads that your interface does. To specify an actual implementation for the method you need to use an extra implementation signature :

```
class A { p: string }

class B { b: string}

class C { c: string}

interface Builder {
    build(paramOne: A): string;
    build(paramOne: B, paramTwo: C): number;
}

class Test implements Builder {

    build(paramOne: A): string;
    build(paramOne: B, paramTwo: C): number;
    build(paramOne: A|B, paramTwo?: C) : string | number {
    return 'string';
    }
}

new Test().build(new A()) // return string 
new Test().build(new B(), new C()) // returns number
new Test().build(new A(), new C())  // error implementation signature is not callable directly
```

You can implement the function as a member field instead of a method if you want to avoid specifying the overloads again, but this is less safe (I had to use `any` as the return type to get the new function to be compatible with the overloads). And there are performance implications to using a field (which is assigned on the instance) instead of a method (which is assigned on the prototype)

```
class Test implements Builder {

    build: Builder ['build'] = function (this: Test, paramOne: A|B, paramTwo?: C) : any {
        return 'string';

    }
}
```

Comment: So I need to repeat this on every class that implements Builder?

Comment: @undefined yes you do unfortunately .. there is a way to do it if you use a function field instead of a method.. i'll add